# Haskell elem function definition has t a can you explain that

Tags: haskell

I was looking at the type annotation of function `elem`. It looked like this:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> t a -> Bool
```

I understand that `Eq a =>` is a type constraint.
So `a` must support `==`.

But I don't understand `t a`, where does this `t` came from ?
What does it do? Why is it necessary?

Link: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem

Comment: notice that the definition of `elem` is within the `Foldable` class. So `t` is the foldable container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `t` is a `Foldable` typeclass, since it is defined in the [**`Foldable`** class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable), so the signature is:

```
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

`elem` thus not only works on a list (where `t ~ []`), but on any `Foldable`, so `t ~ Maybe`, `t ~ NonEmpty`, `t ~ Tree`, etc. Its [default implementation is [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#elem):

> ```
> elem :: Eq a => a -> t a -> Bool
> elem = any . (==)
> ```

It thus checks if any element of the `Foldable` is equal to the query element.

This thus means that it can also work for a `Maybe a` for example where `Nothing` can be seen as an empty collection, and `Just x` as a collection with one element: `x`, or for example look if the element is one of the values in a rose tree [**`Tree a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Tree).

Comment: Now I understand the `t` is from `class Foldable t where`.